# Give submenu full column width using jQuery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a menu that has some links in two levels.
What I am trying to do is to make it so that when you click on the top level then level 2 opens.
Right now my problem is that I want to have two columns but I want level two to be one full width column.

See my codepen here: http://codepen.io/mathiasha/pen/KdzmBL

I don't know if it's easiest to make it in CSS or jQuery.
I dont have control of the HTML.

```
<div class="block block-menu-block">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">6</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">6.1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

See the CSS below:

```
.block-menu-block {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul.menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: -1px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a ~ ul a {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: So is the problem here that you can't decide *which* solution to use (CSS or JavaScript) or that you don't know how to do it at all?

Comment: The problem is don't know how to get the desired effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

As long as first level LIs are set to be `width:50%`, children are bounded. Setting sub-level absolutely positionned could have been a solution, but in your case, it breaks the desired effect.

So a "dirty" solution that I can give you is to use this :

```
.block-menu-block ul li ul{ width:200%; margin-left:-100%; }
.block-menu-block ul li ul li{ width:100%; background:#fff;}
```

Sub-level UL width will be multiplied by two, and then has the same width as the menu. Used negative margin to make a translation, otherwise, it will start under the parent LI and will expend out of the menu boundaries.

And finally, reset the sub LIs width to 100% (background is used to hide parent borders).

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYMWBZ)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but there is still something wrong with it. Menus 3.x are not properly aligned.

Comment: I found a way to do it using nth-child.

`.block-menu-block ul li{
    &:nth-child(even){
        clear: right;
        ul{
            width:200%;
            margin-left:-100%;
            li{
                background: purple;
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
    }
    &:nth-child(odd){
        clear: left;
        ul{
            width:200%;
            li{
                background: black;
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
    }
    
`
See here: http://codepen.io/mathiasha/pen/bVpMyo